# Pandas Dataframe - return datetime column in a np.where statement

Tags: pandas, numpy

My initial dataframe (df):

```
      column1     column2    column3  column4
0  criteria_1  criteria_a   1/5/2017        5
1  criteria_1  criteria_b   2/3/2017        3
2  criteria_1  criteria_a  1/10/2017       10
3  criteria_1  criteria_b   2/7/2017        7
4  criteria_1  criteria_b  2/11/2017       11
5  criteria_1  criteria_a  1/13/2017       13
```

My code:

```
    df = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/Desktop/maxtest.csv")
    df['column3'] = pd.to_datetime(df['column3'])
    df['max_column3'] = df.groupby(['column1','column2'])['column3'].transform(max)
    df['max_column4'] = df.groupby(['column1','column2'])['column4'].transform(max)
    df['test'] = np.where(df['column3'] < df['max_column3'],df['column3'],df['max_column4'])
```

The issue:

I created a df['test'] column and wish to return df['column3'] when the np.where statement is True. When I try this I receive a "TypeError: invalid type promotion" error.

I am not entirely sure what is causing the error.

Comment: I think the problem is your mixing the results of you np.where. Sometimes it will return a datetime other times it returns a str or int.  Pandas dataframes and numpy NDarrays require one dtype per column.    I was able to get around this error by .astype(str) on df.column3.

Answer (score 0):

See my comment for explanation.

```
df['column3'] = pd.to_datetime(df['column3'])
df['max_column3'] = df.groupby(['column1','column2'])['column3'].transform(max)
df['max_column4'] = df.groupby(['column1','column2'])['column4'].transform(max)
df['test'] = np.where((df['column3'] < df['max_column3']),df.column3.astype(str),df.max_column4)
```

Output:

```
      column1     column2    column3  column4 max_column3  max_column4  \
0  criteria_1  criteria_a 2017-01-05        5  2017-01-13           13   
1  criteria_1  criteria_b 2017-02-03        3  2017-02-11           11   
2  criteria_1  criteria_a 2017-01-10       10  2017-01-13           13   
3  criteria_1  criteria_b 2017-02-07        7  2017-02-11           11   
4  criteria_1  criteria_b 2017-02-11       11  2017-02-11           11   
5  criteria_1  criteria_a 2017-01-13       13  2017-01-13           13   

         test  
0  2017-01-05  
1  2017-02-03  
2  2017-01-10  
3  2017-02-07  
4          11  
5          13
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retain the datetime format, you can do:

```
df['test'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.column3 if x.column3 < x.max_column3 else x.max_column4, axis=1)

df
Out[1291]: 
      column1     column2    column3  column4 max_column3  max_column4  \
0  criteria_1  criteria_a 2017-01-05        5  2017-01-13           13   
1  criteria_1  criteria_b 2017-02-03        3  2017-02-11           11   
2  criteria_1  criteria_a 2017-01-10       10  2017-01-13           13   
3  criteria_1  criteria_b 2017-02-07        7  2017-02-11           11   
4  criteria_1  criteria_b 2017-02-11       11  2017-02-11           11   
5  criteria_1  criteria_a 2017-01-13       13  2017-01-13           13   

                  test  
0  2017-01-05 00:00:00  
1  2017-02-03 00:00:00  
2  2017-01-10 00:00:00  
3  2017-02-07 00:00:00  
4                   11  
5                   13
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a standard function and doing:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

    df = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/andre_000/Desktop/maxtest.csv")
    df['column3'] = pd.to_datetime(df['column3'])
    df['max_column3'] = df.groupby(['column1','column2'])['column3'].transform(max)
    df['max_column4'] = df.groupby(['column1','column2'])['column4'].transform(max)


    def func(row):
        if row['column3'] < row['max_column3']:
            return row['column3']
        else:
            return row['max_column4']


    df = df.assign(test=df.apply(func, axis=1))
```